# unresolved NameError while writing Blackjack gameflow

Tags: python, python-2.x, blackjack

I am currently writing a game of Blackjack using python 2.7. as part of the app's gameflow I have defined a new function called `player_turn()`, in which I required a user input that would result in different scenarios depending on the input ("hit" would give the player another card, and "hold" would end the player's turn and pass it on to the dealer. otherwise would result in a customized error)

```
def player_turn():
    if sum(player_card_numbers) < 21:
        user_decision = input('would you like to hit or hold?')
        if user_decision == 'hit':
            player_cards.append(deck.draw())
            print player_cards, dealer_cards
            player_turn()

        elif user_decision == 'hold':
            print "Dealer's turn!"
            dealer_turn()
        else:
            print "player must choose 'hit' or 'hold'"
            player_turn()

    elif sum(player_card_numbers) == 21:
        print "Blackjack!"
        dealer_turn()

    else:
        print "Player Burnt! \nDealer's turn!"
        dealer_turn()
```

It is worth mentioning that the code was originally written in python 3.7, and was changed later on. the code worked perfectly with 3.7.

Now I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'hit' is not defined
```

I would love some advice on how to solve this issue, as well as an explanation on why this would happen. `:)`

Comment: An error like that might occur when you use a variable named `hit` before assigning anything to it. Since the code you've shared does not have a variable named `hit`, the problem must be somewhere else in your program. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Including a full backtrace would be very useful, as well.

Comment: I very much doubt that the above code (slightly modified so e.g. `print` is used as a function) worked perfectly in Python 3.7 (which hasn't dropped the requirement that a name be defined before referenced)

Comment: why would i need to define "hit" before using it? the code takes user input... i defined that if the user input is equal to the string "hit", an if statement would take place. why would "hit" actually need to mean anything at all, besides being a string that initiates the if statment?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
user_decision = input('would you like to hit or hold?')
```

In Python2, `input()` has an `eval()` nature to it, so it's evaling your answer: hit

```
>>> user_decision = input('would you like to hit or hold?')
would you like to hit or hold?hit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hit' is not defined
>>>
```

The coding standard for Python 2 is to not use `input()` but rather use `raw_input()` instead:

```
>>> user_decision = raw_input('would you like to hit or hold?')
would you like to hit or hold?hit
>>> user_decision
'hit'
>>>
```

In Python 3, the `input()` function is equivalent to `raw_input()` in Python 2.